# Show that $p\equiv 1\bmod{4}$ implies $(p)=\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{q}$ in Gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I have to prove that in $\mathbf{Z}[i]$, $p\equiv 1\bmod{4}$ implies that the ideal $(p)$ decomposes in product of two distinct prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{q}$ (*without* using that $p\equiv1\bmod{4}$ implies that $p$ can be written as sum of two squares).

The hint given is: show that $(p)$ is only contained in two coprime maximal ideals.

I can use the result that $-1$ is a square in $\mathbf{F}_p$. What I have so far is the following:

Since $p\equiv 1\mod{4}$, there exists $\alpha\in \mathbf{F}_p^\times$ such that $a^2=-1$. Now $X^2+1$ decomposes in $(X-a)(X+a)\in \mathbf{F}_p[X]$. The ideals $(X-a)$ and $(X+a)$ are clearly coprime, so by the Chinese Remainder Theorem:

$$\frac{\mathbf{Z}[i]}{(p)}\cong \frac{\mathbf{F}_p[X]}{(X^2+1)}\cong \frac{\mathbf{F}_p[X]}{(X-a)(X+a)}\cong \mathbf{F}_p\times \mathbf{F}_p.$$

I am tempted to say now that we have $(p)=(i-a)(i+a)$ by the above isomorphisms, but I don't think this is right.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you keep track of your isomorphisms, you will see that your surjective morphism $\mathbb{Z}[i]\to \mathbb{F}_p^2$ sends $x+iy$ to $(x+ay \mod p,x-ay \mod p)$.

tHe maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ containing $(p)$ corresponding to each copy of $\mathbb{F}_p$ are $(-a+i)$ and $(a+i)$ So your work seems fine to me...

Comment: @GreginGre I see, but then why is $(p)$ 'equal' to $(-a+i)(a+i)$? and not only contained in?

Comment: Some generator is missing.

Comment: @eduard what do you mean?

Comment: The equality of ideals $(p)=(i-a)(i+a)$ does not hold in general. Try with $(p)=(p,i-a)(p,i+a)$. Also, one can use that $\mathbb Z[i]$ is principal (hence Dedekind domain) to deal with the missing inclusion in your comment.